# Android set ActionBar Overflow Popup Menu to match_parent

Tags: android, popup

I want to make each menu item that is shown when we press the overflow button in actionbar to fill the screen width.

I tried using

```
  <style name="PopupWindowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Base.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>
```

But this is not working.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You defined PopupWindowStyle, but do you applied it to android:popupMenuStyle attribute in your app theme?

Comment: yes I had <style name="PopupMenuStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/theme</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    </style>

Comment: I see. But it's just a style. You need to define you own app theme, apply it to you app or Activity, and set <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenuStyle</item> in it.

Comment: I have applied the style to my activity

Comment: Show your theme content, please.